# Ubuntu without a CD

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I need a way to download Ubuntu without the "power to go". I don't have a DvD that is size able enough to fit Ubuntu, but I have an external hard drive or a flash drive that I can use to transfer the files to a fresh computer, meaning nothing is on it yet.

I would be willing to try anything someone says I should do to get Ubuntu on it, without using a CD or DvD

Comment: There are both CD/DVD **and** [USB install instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) linked from the download page. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you get Windows, you will be able to get the ISO, mount it on a virtual DVD driver (like Daemon Tools, for example) and then install Ubuntu with Wubi.